# Spring webflux stream dynamically constructed big zip file

Tags: spring, stream, zip, spring-webflux, large-files

I'd like to create an endpoint with spring webflux, where i create a zip file with multiple files. I create these files dynamically from some database queries as well. Since this zip file can be big, i want to stream the processed data to the client immediately instead of building the whole zip file, and return it. How do i achieve this? There are multiple MVC explanations with the injection of  **HttpServletResponse** , but there is no such thing in Spring Webflux. Here's what i have so far, but it's just downloading a **"response.html"** file, and even if i modify it to "response.zip", the file is corrupted.

````
    @GetMapping(path = "/test", produces = "application/octet-stream")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource>> test(
        @ApiIgnore ServerHttpRequest request,
        @ApiIgnore ServerHttpResponse httpResponse
    ) {
        try {
            String str = "Hello";
            byte[] strToBytes = str.getBytes();
            FileSystemResource zipFile = new FileSystemResource("result.zip");
            ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFile.getFile()));
            ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry("1/Hello.txt");
            out.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
            out.write(strToBytes);

            out.close();
            return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=result.zip")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                .body(zipFile));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return Mono.empty();
        }
    }
    ```
````

Answer (score 1):

You can create a flux emitter that stays active till the emitter completes.

Below is an example approach using `Resource` but this could easily be updated to `inputStream` or `Flux<DataBuffer>` from external sources.

```java
public class ZipDataBuffer {

    final DefaultDataBufferFactory factory = new DefaultDataBufferFactory();
    final DefaultDataBuffer buffer = factory.allocateBuffer(1024);
    final ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(buffer.asOutputStream());

    public static Flux<DataBuffer> toFlux(Resource... resources) {
        var zipDataBuffer = new ZipDataBuffer();
        return Flux.create(emitter -> Flux.fromArray(resources)
                .flatMap(zipDataBuffer::write)
                .doFinally(s -> {
                    emitter.next(zipDataBuffer.finish());
                    emitter.complete();
                })
                .subscribe(emitter::next));
    }

    public Mono<DataBuffer> write(Resource resource) {
        var dataBufferFlux = DataBufferUtils.read(resource, factory, 1024);
        return DataBufferUtils.join(dataBufferFlux)
                .doOnNext(dataBuffer -> write(resource.getFilename(), dataBuffer))
                .thenReturn(read());
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    private synchronized void write(String filename, DataBuffer dataBuffer) {
        try (var is = dataBuffer.asInputStream()) {
            var zipEntry = new ZipEntry(filename);
            zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
            zos.write(is.readAllBytes());
            zos.closeEntry();
        }
    }

    private DataBuffer read() {
        return buffer.split(buffer.writableByteCount());
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    public DataBuffer finish() {
        zos.finish();
        zos.close();
        return read();
    }
}
```