# Webflux streaming DataBuffer with zip resulting in corrupt file

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, nonblocking

Currently I'm implementing a non blocking i/o application with Spring Boot 2.7.12 and Webflux to download files with a webclient, zip them and stream the zip file to the browser.
Downloading and zipping is working fine if I write the ZipOutputStream to a local file.
However, if I stream the zip back to the caller (Flux) it is corrupted.

I'm not sure, if I misunderstand the concept of the DataBuffer, or if it is a bug in the spring framework.

I have created a small sample. If you download the zip file, each entry is duplicated multiple times and the last entry is corrupted.

Thank you
Roberto

```
@GetMapping(value = "/zip", produces = "application/zip")
  public Flux<DefaultDataBuffer> zip() {
    var files = Arrays.asList("File1", "File2", "File3", "File4", "File5");
    var responseDataBuffer = new DefaultDataBufferFactory().allocateBuffer();
    ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(responseDataBuffer.asOutputStream());
    return Flux.fromStream(files.stream())
        .map(file -> putZipEntry(file, zipOutputStream))
        .map(x -> responseDataBuffer)
        .doOnComplete(() -> closeZipOutputStream(zipOutputStream));
  }

  private void closeZipOutputStream(ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream) {
    try {
    zipOutputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  private ZipOutputStream putZipEntry(String file, ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream) {
    try {
      zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file + ".txt"));
      zipOutputStream.write(file.getBytes());
      zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
      return zipOutputStream;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into a similar problem of wanting to zip Flux from multiple URLs. The problem was how ZipOutputStream was closed. It was missing the end of the file. Thus the corruption.

Try calling finish() on the zip stream and adding those last few bytes to the Flux.

Example code can be found here.

[Spring webflux stream dynamically constructed big zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65146044/spring-webflux-stream-dynamically-constructed-big-zip-file/77533371#77533371)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this simpler approach:

```
private static final String ZIP_FILE = "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";

private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 10;

@GetMapping(value = "/zip", produces = "application/zip")
public Flux<DataBuffer> test() {
    return DataBufferUtils.readInputStream(() -> new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.getDecoder().decode(ZIP_FILE)), new DefaultDataBufferFactory(), BUFFER_SIZE);
}
```

Comment: As stated this was just a sample extraction of a much more complex implementation. In the real implementation I need to write in a separate dataBuffer backed OutputStream which is written by a ZipOutPutStream.

Comment: Nonsense. A `Flux<DataBuffer>` is a `Flux<DataBuffer>`. And really, `Flux.fromStream(IntStream.of(1).boxed())`? This is going to get 'much more complex'?

Comment: I have changed my example. Hopefully it is clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

`getFluxPublisherFunction` is incorrect and logic does not make sense. What it is doing is

> > DataBufferUtils.write(source, outputStream)

source is Flux of DataBuffer from ZIP_FILE. OutputStream is another data buffer created with separate buffer (named defaultDataBuffer). **This method returns same buffers as in source**

> > .map(buffer -> defaultDataBuffer)

For each buffer ( chunk of ZIP_file), it returns complete destimation buffer which is getting populated using write operation. Destination buffer at any point might contain one of more parts of ZIP_FILE.

1. Why code works with 1000 buffer is because this is sufficient buffer to contain the entire contents of ZIP_FILE. `getRead` method in this case returns single DataBuffer when `DataBufferUtils.write(source, outputStream)` is subscribed. This does not work when buffer size is small because you are returning partial chunks accumulated in defaultDataBuffer.
2. To return zip to browser, simply return the Flux created by `getRead` method with different buffers. It will work of buffer size of 10 or 100 or 1000.

Comment: You are right, thank you. I have change my example, as this is not the initial cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how Spring handles that, but to my understanding it has no knowledge of when you finish the writing and you return the buffer as soon as you have first chunk written to it. So I guess that is what the receiver sees too. In this case what you need is to return the Data Buffer only when it is fully written.

Try this:

```
return Flux.fromStream(files.stream())
    .map(file -> putZipEntry(file, zipOutputStream))
    .then(Mono.fromCallable { 
        closeZipOutputStream(zipOutputStream);
        responseDataBuffer
   })
```

PS in your case it doesn't make sense to use Reactor because you write it to a single buffer and wait until it finishes. It would be better if you produce response in chunks, but I don't see how you can do that with standard `ZipOutputStream`. However, since it already produces an `OutputStream` it would be easier just to produce it as is (with `InputStreamResource` and `ResponseEntity`)

Comment: If I set breakpoints at zipOutputStream.write and zipOutputStream.close I can see the download in the browser is still open. Each time zipOutputStream.write the received bytes are increasing. Only after the I resume processing the flux to the end (when doOnComplete terminates) the download finishes in the browser. So webflux seems to wait until the flux is processed completely. In the real implementation the files are streamed from a webclient and can be couple of gigabytes. Therefore  I would prefer to use reactor.

Comment: That's interesting, I'm curious to know how Spring learns that you're still writing to it. Regarding the gigabyte long files, that's exactly my concern, because you don't use Reactor to optimize it and you would write it to the memory. If you want to have a streaming response chunk by chunk you have to reconsider your zipping code design

Comment: Webflux subscribes the Flux. So it knows, when the flux is finished.

Comment: I mean `responseDataBuffer`. You return it at the first step and then continue writing to it (as to a memory buffer) and I'm not sure how Webflux should decide it should stop reading from it, and also not read from the beginning multiple times

Comment: Anyway, do I understand correctly that you've tried the suggested fix and it didn't work too?

Comment: I have tried the suggested fix. In this case the zip file is fine, but is completely buffered in memory. Streaming to the client only starts after it the flux has been processed completely.

Comment: Yes, that's how it would work with `DataBuffer` and that's why I'm suggesting to respond with `OutputStream` instead

Comment: Returning an `OutputStream` is not possible with Webflux: `org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No Encoder for [java.io.OutputStream] with preset Content-Type 'null'`

Comment: Did you return it as `Mono<ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>>`?

Comment: Just to clarify. The approach with returning a `Flux<DataBuffer>` is possible too, but you'll need special code for handling the reader, writer and chunks. That's a bit more of code. And it makes sense to write it only when you have everything else as a Flux. But to my understanding your have just files already downloaded and it's just a plain single-thread algorithm that doesn't use much of reactive waiting so it doesn't make sense to over-complicate it since the standard Input/OutputStream does everything efficiently.